# How to only add unique values to a useState array and maintain maximum of length 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am trying to add max 3 values to a useState array and ensure all are unique and if fourth unique element is pushed it will replace the first element  at index 0. ? Also, if the same element is clicked then it is removed from the array. However the function I wrote is not able to accomplish my objective.

```
 const [chatbox,setChatBox]=useState([]);
        
        chat=['a11','b11','c11','d11']
        
        chat.map((c)=>(
              <div
                 onClick={()=>addorRemoveitems(c)}
               >
                {c}
             <div>
          ))
               
             const addorRemoveitems=(cId)=>{
                              if (
                                  chatbox.length <= 3 &&
                                  chatbox.includes(cId)
                                ) {
                                  const newArray = chatbox.filter(
                                    (c) => c !== cId
                                  );
                                  setChatBox(newArray);
                                } else if (
                                  chatbox.length < 3 &&
                                  chatbox.indexOf(cId) === -1
                                ) {
                                  setChatBox((prev) => [...prev, cId]);
                                } else if (
                                  chatbox.length == 3 &&
                                  chatbox.indexOf(cId) !== -1
                                ) {
                                  const newArray = chatbox.splice(
                                    0,
                                    1,
                                    cId
                                  );
                                  setChatBox(newArray);
                                }
                     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify this a tad I guess to fit how you are adding new items to the list. Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-e32wlp?file=/src/index.tsx

```
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  const [newItemGen, setNewItemGen] = useState(0);

  const addOrRemoveItemFromArray = (item) => {
    if (array.includes(item)) {
      setArray((prevState) =>
        prevState.filter((existing) => existing !== item)
      );
    } else {
      setArray((prevState) => [item, ...prevState.slice(0, 2)]);
      setNewItemGen((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <div>
        Items in array :
        {array.map((item) => (
          <button onClick={() => addOrRemoveItemFromArray(item)}>{item}</button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => addOrRemoveItemFromArray(`newItem${newItemGen}`)}
        >
          add item
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the item is already in the array, filter it out.  If not, add the item to a slice of the old array which only captures the first two values.

EDIT:
I just realised you want to check that a value is unique before adding it to the list.  You'll have to create a function for adding and function for removing then.

```
  const addItem = (item) => {
    if (!array.includes(item)) {
      setArray((prevState) => [item, ...prevState.slice(0, 2)]);
      setNewItemGen((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }
  };

  const removeItemFromArray = (item) => {
      setArray((prevState) =>
        prevState.filter((existing) => existing !== item)
      );
  };
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you for taking the time to provide the solution